# Faster to access numeric property by string or integer?

Tags: javascript, performance

In JavaScript you can get and set indexes of arrays and "numeric" properties of objects using either an integer or a string and get the same results:

```
var a=[], o={};
a[1]    = "foo";  a["1"]   == "foo" // true
a["2"]  = "bar";  a[2]     == "bar" // true
a["-3"] = "baz";  a[-.3e1] == "baz" // true
o[1]    = "foo";  o["1"]   == "foo" // true
o["2"]  = "bar";  o[2]     == "bar" // true
o["-3"] = "baz";  o[-.3e1] == "baz" // true
```

While strings and numbers are interopable—for both getting and setting—which is faster (for both arrays and for objects)?

Comment: The key can actually be anything, not just an integer or string.

Comment: @MikeChristensen not entirely true, other objects are converted to strings. To demonstrate it: `var o={},a=[];o[a]=2;alert(o[""])`

Comment: Integers are also converted to strings. That is `a[1]` and `a["1"]` occupy the same slot. For objects `o[{}]` and `o["[object Object]"]` also occupy the same slot

Comment: Is a micro-optimization question really getting this many upvotes?

Comment: @JuanMendes You can also argue that strings are converted to integers if possible. `var a=[];a["42"]=1;a.length==43`

Comment: @Lekensteyn I disagree, your arguments is that calling `a.length` looks for all the properties, converts to integers, and returns the highest value.

Comment: @JohnFx I'm as surprised as you. :) I just wanted to add my investigations to the public knowledge, not vote whore. (Though, Firefox being almost **60x** faster for integers on arrays is sort of non-trivial.)

Comment: @JohnFx It's very likely that this is micro optimization, but it's fun. If you really want fast array access, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays

Comment: I'm not downvoting it, even though I normally might. It sounds like the community is okay with it this time and that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, integers are faster for array access than strings. Perhaps surprisingly, they are *also* faster than strings for object properties.

### http://jsperf.com/string-vs-integer-array-indices

[image]

### http://jsperf.com/string-vs-integer-object-indices

[image]

Comment: Nice question, nice answer. This'll be factoring into my JS stuff soon I bet.

Comment: To me this is surprising, since Arrays extend Object, which accesses keys by strings. So I would assume that integers have to be converted to strings so they can be hashed. But there's probably some optimization for integers (maybe the integer is the hash)

Comment: @Jay: Chrome is on average the best-- the longer the bar the better the browser's performance. :)

Comment: @Elliot Bonneville: That makes sense then, thought the x axis would be time.

Comment: jsperf seems to have died. You may want to update this at some point since we can no longer see how you tested it. It may also be interesting to see if more recent browsers are notably different. Not that integers will ever be slower than strings, of course.